# Array index increment

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in php code. I want to have that whenever page is being called it should print value of first array index and when next time second value of array index and so on... what modification I could do? for now it´s printing everything when being called single time.

```
<html>
<?php
$addresses = array('ifcbxespra', 'ifcheqjbmea', 'ifcqiknsa', 'ifcqirtjla', 'ifcwqsrlmn', 'ifclmkmzhz','ifcwdujhgc','ifcihddngh','icffhzudcd','ifchnsqzgs','ifcgssqrhg');

foreach ($addresses as &$value) {
    echo  $value ;
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you propose to track when it is called? How many times it is called? Do you want to only increment if the same visitor calls the page? Or do you want it to increment to first if user A views it, then increment again if user B views it, etc.

Comment: So you have made no attempt what so ever to try and achieve your requirement yourself! So this is a _do it for me_ question right

Comment: @cale_b yesss before I was using array_rand function in which it is automatically random number is being called and print so there is no uniqueness. yess I want to call it 11 time as size of array. and as you told when user A views it then  ifcbxespra, and When user B visits next value which is ifcheqjbmea.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Before I used array rand function in which random value is being picked from array but as I mentioned above I need to have output like that and I am not used to do programming much so needed help

Comment: @Ravi you should take some books about web development and understand the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem with the MySQL. created a column with all code. and then call the script every-time when user press button. In the script first I fetch first raw and print that value, and then, delete that raw. so every-time user will get unique value from the list of code And it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `$_SESSION` and store there the last `index`.

For example:

```
$array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

if (!$_SESSION['nextIndex'] || $_SESSION['nextIndex'] >= count($array)) {
  $_SESSION['nextIndex'] = 0
}

// print the value 
echo $array[$_SESSION['nextIndex']];

// increment the nextIndex
$_SESSION['nextIndex']++;
```

NOTE: This will only work for the same user. Each page reload will increment the array index. But if you need some cross-user counting, then you have to store the information somewhere on the server, like a DB or even a simple txt file.

Check out this example: http://hibbard.eu/how-to-make-a-simple-visitor-counter-using-php/

Comment: This won't work based on OP's comment that this should change regardles of which user looks at the page.  If user A looks, should be first entry, then if user B looks, should be second entry, etc.  $_SESSION won't store across different users / browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want. But if you want to print the first array's value when the page loads one time, the second array's value when the page loads another time and so on, you can do this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($addresses) || empty($addresses)){  //checks if the array is not initialized or if it's empty
   $addresses = array('ifcbxespra', 'ifcheqjbmea', 'ifcqiknsa', 'ifcqirtjla', 'ifcwqsrlmn', 'ifclmkmzhz','ifcwdujhgc','ifcihddngh','icffhzudcd','ifchnsqzgs','ifcgssqrhg');
   echo $addresses[0];  //print the first value
   array_splice($addresses, 0, 1);  //removes the first element of the array and reindexes it 
}else{
    echo $addresses[0];  //print the first value
    array_splice($addresses, 0, 1);  //removes the first element of the array and reindexes it
}
```

The logic behinds it is: if the array already exists and is not empty (it has values), print the first value and then remove it, so next time the first value will be the second actual value. When the array is empty, redefine it as to start again.

You can search for more information on array_splice() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

P.S.: you have to use [PHP's $_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) to save the array between the pages.

Comment: This won't work based on OP's comment that this should change regardles of which user looks at the page.  If user A looks, should be first entry, then if user B looks, should be second entry, etc.  $_SESSION won't store across different users / browsers.